# Split out JSON input and apply same JSON field name as column name in Alteryx workflow

Tags: alteryx

I'm using Alteryx 2019.3 and looking to build a workflow which uses JSON as input.  When it reads the JSON it puts the JSON key value pairs into columns called JSON_Name and JSON_ValueString

In an example I have mocked up, the field names in the JSON below looks like this in the JSON_Name column:

```
customer.0.name
customer.0.contactDetails.0.company
customer.0.contactDetails.0.addressDetails.0.address
customer.0.contactDetails.0.addressDetails.0.addressType
customer.0.departments.0.name
```

What I want to do is the split it out into different tables and have the last part of the JSON_Name value as the column name so it looks something like this (caps show table name):

```
CUSTOMER
customerId

CONTACTDETAILS
customerId
company

ADDRESSDETAILS
customerId
address
addressType

DEPARTMENTS
customerId
name
```

How do I do this in Alteryx and how can I get it to work when I'm there can be multiple entries in the JSON list?

Thanks for any help

**JSON input (mock up for example)**

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "contactDetails": [{
        "company": "company1",
        "addressDetails": 
        [{
            "address": "City1",
            "addressType": "Business"
        }]
    }]
    "departments": 
    [{
        "name": "dept1
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Text to columns and then a series of filters to split it into different datasets (tables). You probably want to use crosstabs to get the format of the tables right.